# How to plot graph involving complex numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, graph, matplotlib, typeerror

I want to plot a graph of the magnitude of `1/(1+(i)(omega)(tau))` against frequency `f`, where `i` is the imaginary number, `omega=(2)(pi)(f)`, `tau` is a constant. The following is the first part of the code:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

f=np.logspace(-2,4,10)
tau=1.0
omega=2*np.pi*f
y=np.complex(1,omega*tau)
print y
```

But I get this `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. What's the problem? Why can't I put `f` (which is an array right?) to `y`? By the way, I am using `enthought canopy`.

*One more question:* What's the difference between `pylab` and `matplotlib`? Different modules? If I'm just plotting graphs, dealing with complex numbers and matrix, which one should I use?

Comment: Just ran your code, and the problem is happening in `y=np.complex(1,omega*tau)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of having to use `np.vectorize`. That is,

```
  def main():
        f = np.logspace(-2,4,10)
        print(f)
        tau=1.0
        omega=2*np.pi*f
        y=np.vectorize(complex)(1,omega*tau)
        print (y)
```

, will return first:

```
[  1.00000000e-02   4.64158883e-02   2.15443469e-01   1.00000000e+00
   4.64158883e+00   2.15443469e+01   1.00000000e+02   4.64158883e+02
   2.15443469e+03   1.00000000e+04]
```

And then return:

```
[ 1. +6.28318531e-02j  1. +2.91639628e-01j  1. +1.35367124e+00j
  1. +6.28318531e+00j  1. +2.91639628e+01j  1. +1.35367124e+02j
  1. +6.28318531e+02j  1. +2.91639628e+03j  1. +1.35367124e+04j
  1. +6.28318531e+04j]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't construct numpy arrays with `np.complex`. In python when you put a `j` after a number it makes it imaginary. Thus, to make complex arrays simply do:

```
y = 1 + omega * tau * 1j
```